# Non-split extension of an extraspecial 3-group by SL(2,3)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Let $Q$ be an extraspecial $3$-group of order $3^5$. I am curious about the existence of a group $G$ satisfies the following condition.

(1) $G$ is a non-split extension of $Q$ by the special linear group $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$ where $Q$ is normal in $G$;

(2) If $P$ is a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$, then every element of order $3$ in $P$ is contained in $Q$.

(3) The action of Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ on $Q/Z(Q)$ is Frobenius.

Also, it will be great if someone could construct this group by GAP. Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: May I ask how this question came about?

Comment: It is from split extension of extraspecial $3$-group of order $3^5$ by $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$. In order to construct such non-split extension, one could start to construct a split extension of $Q$ by quaternion group of order $8$. And the action of quaternion group of order $8$ on $Q/Z(Q)$ should be Frobenius. Since we are going to construct a non-split extension of $Q$ by $SL(2,3)$, we need some element of order exceeding 3 outside $Q$.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your point @DavidA.Craven  However, I have an idea to construct such a group in GAP by the following steps: 1. Start with all groups of order 1944; 2. Filtered all groups with derived subgroup of order 648 which are only 4 groups. 3. Calculate the Schur multipliers of the 4 group. 4. Take suitable factor groups of Schur covering of the 4 groups. However, the function SchurCover in GAP is weird, I try to calculate the order of a Schur covering group, but it doesn't return a value for a long time.

Comment: My point was that I was counting extensions of $3^5$ by $6$, not $3^5$ by $24$. Comment deleted.

Comment: I see your point. If the group I desired exists, it should has a subgroup $H$ of order $3^5\cdot 6$  such that $H'$ is an extraspecial group of order $3^5$ and $Z(H)$ of order 3. So, one could filter all groups of order $3^5\cdot 6$ to get $H$. Checking your idea in GAP, one of the possible case for $H$ is SmallGroup(1458,1725) in which every $3$-element outside $H'$ has order $9$. Although it looks that there are some distance from the final goal, I  would like to thank you for your brilliant idea @DavidA.Craven

Comment: The problem with GAP's SchurCover is that it returns a finitely presented group. Computing its order can time a long time. It might be faster to use NonsplitExtension from the cohomolo packge or just Extensions (see Section 46.8 in the GAP manual).

Comment: @user44312 I actually meant that I was thinking of $SL(2,2)$ rather than $SL(2,3)$ !

Comment: Ah, that is the reason. Thanks very much! @BrauerSuzuki

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Your idea still give me some hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the second remark about groups of 1944:

```
gap> l:=AllSmallGroups(Size,1944,x->Size(DerivedSubgroup(x)),648);
[ <pc group of size 1944 with 8 generators>,
  <pc group of size 1944 with 8 generators>,
  <pc group of size 1944 with 8 generators>,
  <pc group of size 1944 with 8 generators> ]
```

Form a trivial module for 8 generators over $\mathbb{F}_3$, and construct extensions for the first group:

```
gap> m:=TrivialModule(8,GF(3));;
gap> e:=Extensions(l[1],m);;
```

Now we write a function to test for the conditions you require. For each extension we retroactively identify the group $Q$ (and make sure it is unique), we then test the 3 conditions

```
Testfun:=function(g)
local q,nat,a;
  # find q
  q:=List(GQuotients(g,SL(2,3)),Kernel);
  if Length(q)>1 then Error("more than one possible q");fi;
  q:=q[1];
  # Non-split
  if Length(ComplementClassesRepresentatives(g,q))>0 then return false;fi;
  # No outside element of order 3
  if ForAny(Difference(SylowSubgroup(g,3),q),x->Order(x)=3) then return false;fi;
  # Frobenius action of 2-Sylow
  nat:=NaturalHomomorphismByNormalSubgroup(g,Centre(q));
  a:=Action(Image(nat,SylowSubgroup(g,2)),Image(nat,q));
  if Size(a)<=8 or not IsTransitive(a) then return false;fi;
  return true;
end;
```

and then test the candidate extensions:

```
gap> e:=Filtered(e,Testfun);
[  ]
```

Doing do for the 4 candidate groups does not find a single example, so (unless I've made a mistake in interpreting your conditions) no such group exists.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explicit answer. I try to remove the condition on 3-elements and check the existence of such non-split extension. The result shows that such extension does not exist. @ahulpke